# Google Play Store app using Cordova is rejected for using a webview

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I have a web app that is approved for the Apple App Store already but Google Play gives me the following issue when I try and submit it for approval to the store. It is made with Cordova. I understand the issue is with the WebView loading in the app and that there is no other native features. Is there anything I can add to make this get approved from Google Play? Will adding Push Notifications be enough? It is a holiday themed app.

The Google Play rejection response:

> Webviews
>
> We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website, regardless of ownership, or to aggregate content that does not belong to the developer. To resolve this issue, please remove violating content and resubmit your app.

Comment: How long ago did you submit to Apple store?

Comment: Last month it was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup) push-notifications for Cordova, i hope this native will help you